# Oracle - Filter Duplicate Records

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I am trying to filter duplicate rows based on OPEN_DATE when branch id and employee id are same

Note: I am pulling these columns from multiple tables.I have tried to find answers from other posts but couldn't find.

TABLE ROWS

```
OPENED_DATE   BRANCH_ID  EMPLOYEE_ID 
01/13/2014     100       100121     <- FILTER(SELECT ONLY LATEST OPENED_DATE)
01/29/2014     100       100121     <- FILTER(SELECT ONLY LATEST OPENED_DATE)
02/03/2014     100       100121   
02/03/2014     100       100150
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use an analytic: `max(opened_date) over (partition by Branch_ID, Employee_ID) as Opened_Date`  [DOCS](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions098.htm#SQLRF00666)  be sure group by appropriate fields as needed.

Comment: --------                                                                                                                                   SELECT T_EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNT.EMPLOYEE_ID,
T_EMPLOYEE.ENTRY_ID,
T_EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNT.BRANCH_ID,
T_EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNT.EMPLOYEE_ID,
T_EMPLOYEE.OPENED_ID
FROM T_EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNT
JOIN
T_EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNT.ENTRY_ID = T_EMPLOYEE.ENTRY_ID;

Comment: the from/join is syntactically incorrect.  if you're joining to T_EMPLOYEE you need to do that first then have the `on` clause to show how they relate. `FROM T_EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNT 
INNER JOIN T_EMPLOYEE
  on T_EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNT.ENTRY_ID = T_EMPLOYEE.ENTRY_ID;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use row number on branchid and empid the do order by on date with descending.

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM (SELECT OPENED_DATE
           , BRANCH_ID
           , EMPLOYEE_ID
           , ROW_NUMBER() (OVER PARTITION BY BRANCH_ID , EMPLOYEE_ID ORDER BY OPENED_DATE desc ) rn
      FROM table) as t1 
WHERE rn=1
```

Comment: it seems I am missing something. The below is my actual query                                                       --------                                                                                                                                   SELECT T_EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNT.EMPLOYEE_ID,
T_EMPLOYEE.ENTRY_ID,
T_EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNT.BRANCH_ID,
T_EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNT.EMPLOYEE_ID,
T_EMPLOYEE.OPENED_ID
FROM T_EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNT
JOIN
T_EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNT.ENTRY_ID = T_EMPLOYEE.ENTRY_ID;